# Python Elementtree: Ignore undefined prefixes

Tags: python, xml, undefined, prefix

I have a lot of XML 'fragments' that are collected from a variety of sources. Since these are not fully formed XML documents, quite a few do not have their tag prefixes declared, e.g. tags like `<exch:p> paragraph text </exch:p>`

Using ElementTree in Python to parse these, very often I get the unbounded prefix error. Is there a switch to make the parser ignore the prefixes all together?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can with both lxml and elementtree. The options on [XMLParser](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser) are limited. The error message is coming from the expat parser library. The way to deal with it would be to declare a namespace before the parsing.

In XPath, there is a way to only get the local-name

```
//*[local-name()='p']
```

but XPath is not fully implemented in elementtree as mentionned in the documentation.